# Create a scatter chart by matplotlib with mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create a simple chart with these library written below. Here is how I did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb

def mysql_select_all():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                           user='root',
                           passwd='password',
                           db='databse')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT price,size1 FROM 008_table"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(sql),columns=["price","size1"])
    x = df.price
    y = df.size1
    plt.title("Table", fontsize="24")
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=100)
    plt.xlabel("Size1")
    plt.ylabel("Price")
    plt.tick_params(axis='both',which='major',labelsize=14)
    cursor.close()

print("Start")

mysql_select_all()

print("End")
```

I got the Value Error with this code, where should I fix this code ?

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: There is no specific line. I got only these 2 error.  1)ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2. 2)ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 37), indices imply (2, 37)

Comment: for the record, sometimes it's helpful to comment-out `#` lines of code to isolate where the error is.  In this case, you could have removed all the plotting code and the error still would have occurred at the `DataFrame` line... that would help you understand if the problem is with pyplot, pandas, or SQL.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(sql),columns=["price","size1"])
```

did you mean to type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(result),columns=["price","size1"])
```

?